# Tomcat Deployment of Spring Boot is giving 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot Rest Controller on Tomcat 8.  When I run it directly from Eclipse, it works fine.  But when deploying it to Tomcat 8, I get a 404 error.

I've followed these instructions (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) and searched everywhere, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my Controller:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TomcatController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Collection<String> sayHello() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 10)
          .mapToObj(i -> "Hello number " + i)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
}
```

Here is my Application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SsoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SsoApplication.class);
    }
}
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SSOServices</name>
  <description>SSO Services</description>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  
    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
      <version>2.4.0</version> 
      <relativePath/> 
    </parent> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
To summarize, when I test through eclipse with "localhost:8080/hello", it works.
When I deploy to tomcat 8 and test with "localhost:8080/sso/hello", I get a 404.

Comment: I didn't use tomcat for a very long time, but please check the tomcat configuration too.

Comment: Tomcat is working fine.  If I put test.txt file directly under "webapps/sso" and I can load it with the URL localhost:8080/sso/test.txt.

Comment: For Spring Boot 2.4 to work you would need to use Tomcat 8.5 as minimum (not just 8) or even better tomcat 9. But why bother with deploying instead of just running the war (or better) jar with the embedded container?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  To answer your question, I know it would be easier to run as a container, but my client already has a Tomcat instance completely setup how they want it, and want all their apps together.  Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From M. Deinum (above)

For Spring Boot 2.4 to work you would need to use Tomcat 8.5 as minimum (not just 8) or even better tomcat 9.